# Windows server Allow and deny

Tags: windows, security, permissions

What is the deal with this.  According to my count there are for possible permissions

allow (checked) deny (checked)
not allow (empty) deny (checked)
allow (checked) deny( empty)
allow (empty) deny (empty)

So what is the default permission with both are empty?
What is the permission when both are checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried it?  :)  I'm asking because if you click Deny in the GUI it erases the corresponding Allow permission, and vice versa.

> So what is the default permission with both are empty?

Allow.

> What is the permission when both are checked?

This isn't possible.

(At this point you're probably wondering why deny even exists.  In inherited permissions, deny always supersedes allow.  So, for example, if you wanted to give a user an entire directory and all its subdirectories except one named "forbidden," you could put a deny on forbidden.)

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/uuPhPZZ)  <--- Both can be checked.  Closed the properties box waited a few seconds and band-bing both check.  I think you do not need both deny and allow even in the scenario you propose - its a matter of convinces?   I marked your answers as correct and voted your answer up anway - I think there is not a right answer